# Is there a way to write the following expression as a single identity?

Tags: determinant

while doing a problem I have the following expression

$$\left| \begin{array}{cc} y_2 & y_3 \\ y_2'' & y_3'' \\ \end{array} \right| y_1 + \left| \begin{array}{cc} y_1 & y_3 \\ y_1'' & y_3'' \\ \end{array} \right| y_2 +   \left| \begin{array}{cc} y_1 & y_2 \\ y_1'' & y_2'' \\ \end{array} \right| y_3   $$

Is there a way to write this as just one determinant? a 3by3 determinant of course

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\left |
\begin{array}{ccc}
y_1 & -y_2 & y_3 \\
y_1 & y_2 & y_3 \\
y_1^" & y_2^" & y_3^"
\end{array}
\right |$

Comment: ILoveMath ... and check that you did not make a sign mistake on your middle term

Comment: If ILoveMath made a sign mistake in his second term, then using your determinant method, the result would be zero.